# How to de-select a previous row in a Grid-view?

Tags: gridview

I have gridview with template field of dropdownlist in each row.when i select any value from dropdownlist it will change color of 3rd row below than it.But when i click on another dropdownlist it is changing the color of 3rd row below than it but color of previous row is still stick to it.I want one row colored at a time.How to do it .?
I am doing following.

```
  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
            int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
            GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use Code like below...

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

```
       foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int g1 = gvRow.RowIndex;
            GridView1.Rows[g1].BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
        GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClearSelection()` method of `DataGridView` in order to de-select the rows.